# merging worksheets/tabs within a google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to merge 4 worksheets into an accumulative one, all columns are the same.  But I still need to be able to add, manipulate and filter the data in all the different worksheets, including the accumulative one.

I have combined them using =`{Armes!C3:AC25;Davis!A11:AC31;Riibe!A3:AC25;Winter!B3:AC24}`; but cannot filter new worksheet.

Also tried: `=QUERY({Armes!A3:AC25;Davis!A3:AC31;Riibe!A3:AC25;Winter!A3:AC24})` with same result

I still need to be able to add data and add filters

Comment: share a copy of your sheet pls with some example of what should be the result

Answer (score 1):

You'd get the best results by using the `QUERY` formula, just like the one in your example: `=QUERY({Armes!A3:AC25;Davis!A3:AC31;Riibe!A3:AC25;Winter!A3:AC24})`.

There are 2 ways you can filter your `QUERY`:

1. wrap the `QUERY` formula with `FILTER` formula and arguments:
   `=FILTER(QUERY({Armes!A3:AC25;Davis!A3:AC31;Riibe!A3:AC25;Winter!A3:AC24}), condition1, [condition2, ...])`
2. add the filtering into the `QUERY` itself:
   `=QUERY({Armes!A3:AC25;Davis!A3:AC31;Riibe!A3:AC25;Winter!A3:AC24},"select * where condition1, [condition2, ...])`

One thing you CAN NOT DO is to edit (you used the term "manipulate") the data in the query result table. You can only edit the `QUERY` formula itself, to filter and streamline the result according to your needs.